# Почему возникают nan и inf?

Tags: c

Вот код функции нахождения корней матрицы с помощью метода гаусса, функция работает, все показывает верно, но иногда проскакивают nan и inf, в чем ошибка?

```
void rsly_gauss(double **matrix, double *vector, int n) {
    int index_row, index_col, k;
    double temp;
    /********** Прямой ход **********/
for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    temp = 1 / matrix[k][k]; // для получения единицы на диагонали
    for (index_row = k; index_row < n; index_row++) {
        matrix[k][index_row] =
            matrix[k][index_row] * temp; // преобразуем строку (умножаем на
                                         // обратное числу на диагонали)
    }
    vector[k] = vector[k] * temp;

    for (index_row = k + 1; index_row < n; index_row++) {
        for (index_col = k + 1; index_col < n; index_col++) {
            matrix[index_row][index_col] = matrix[index_row][index_col] -
                matrix[index_row][k] * matrix[k][index_col];
        }
        vector[index_row] =
            vector[index_row] - matrix[index_row][k] * vector[k];
    }
}

for (int index_row = 0; index_row < 3; index_row++) {
    for (int index_col = 0; index_col < 4; index_col++) {
        if (index_col != 3) {
            printf("%.2lf  ", matrix[index_row][index_col]);

        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: inf - результат деления ненулевого значения на ноль, nan - результат деления нуля на ноль (либо умножения inf на ноль).

Answer (score 2):

Ну, у вас там происходят деления, умножения. Если число поделить на слишком маленькое число (или ноль), получится `inf` или `nan`.

Это может быть связано с тем, что матрица у вас близка к сингулярной (плохо обусловлена). Либо вы вообще пытаетесь скормить методу матрицу, у которой ранг меньше порядка.

С первым явлением можно бороться таким образом - можно переставить строки и столбики матрицы так, чтобы на главной деагонали были максимальные по модулю числа в матрице. Понятно, что это никак не изменит решения системы, зато улучшит обусловленность. Для этого есть готовый алгоритм, применяющий перестановку в двудольном графе.

*Кстати, вижу у вас креатив виде получения на главной диагонали единичек (что напротив, портит обусловленность). Вы это сами придумали?*

Со вторым явлением - надо проверять, что у вас образовалась строчка из близких к нулевым значениям, и если образовалась - ругаться.